# How to get the end number the screen cs201010

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

How to get the last number when it shows the warning number.
Acumatica does not allow me to register the last number that would be "MD9".

Now when you try to register the next "MD10" series, MD11 is recorded as shown in the image.

Please could you tell me how I should configure my correlatives so that I register all the series without ignoring a correlative. As shown in this example I did not register the series ("MD9 AND MD10").

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiLiD.png)

[Creacion de la Factura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X7ir.png)

please help me with this interrogant.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to decipher what you're looking for.

If you want to know which is the current last invoice number in the database you can use this SQL query:

```
select top 1 RefNbr from ARRegister where ARRegister.DocType = 'INV'
order by ARRegister.CreatedDateTime desc
```

This is the number that should match with last number. You need to review what's in the database to assess if some numbers are skipped and then set the bounds accordingly.